# Where to look for analysis on Cyber Security market in the UK?

Tags: penetration-test

I work for a company that provides IT solutions. Their service ranges from basic Desktop support to massive data center migration and deployment.

Recently my boss approached me asking about the security field and the potential for investment and feature growth.

I need to create a presentation that shows how moving toward offering penetration testing (both Infrastructure and Web) would be beneficial.

Is there any report or website online that I could use to get this type of information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a lot of good specialist recruitment firms. I don't want to say any names and recommended one over the other, but if you look on linkedin they should be easy to find. Interestingly one the best recruitment guys is a former premiership footballer.

Comment: is this any help? https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/259500/bis-13-1231-competitive-analysis-of-the-uk-cyber-security-sector.pdf